# Increasing the 'stoptime' of generated routes

Tags: sql-server, join, query

I'm learning some basic SQL skills and I was toying around with some data to see what I can do, however, I'm a bit stuck on how to proceed with my current problem.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| RouteID | SegmentID | Order | BeginTime | EndTime  | CarID 
| ------- | --------- | ----- | --------- | -------- | ----- 
| 1       | 45        | 1     | 10:00:30  | 10:01:00 | 1
| 1       | 46        | 2     | 10:01:00  | 10:01:30 | 1
| 1       | 47        | 3     | 10:01:30  | 10:02:00 | 1
| 2       | 50        | 1     | 10:05:00  | 10:05:30 | 1
| 2       | 49        | 2     | 10:06:00  | 10:06:30 | 1
| 3       | 900       | 1     | 20:01:00  | 20:01:30 | 2
```

As you can see, we have a bunch of cars for which we have the driven routes as well. A route is simply a sequence of traveled roadsegments. Furthermore, we have the timestamps of entering the segments and leaving the segments.

**The goal**

What I want to do is to create an easy origin-destination analysis. I'm given a list of segments that belong to location A and similarly, I'm given a list of segments belonging to location B.

**My solution**

Alright, this is easy. I have made a new table that for each route lists the first and last segment. Using this table, it is then super easy to get the answer.

**The problem**

The routes themselves are not generated as they should be. In the above table for example, you'll see that car 1 has two routes. The first route end at 10:02:00 whereas the second route begins at 10:05:00. As the this time difference is less that 5 minutes apart, I'd very much like to consider this as 'one route'. I'm not necessarily interested in generating a new table where we glue all routes of the same car together provided that they lie within 5 minutes of each other (although, I'd be very interested in the type of queries one would have to write to accomplish this).

For now, I'd be very happy to get a clue/answer on how to somehow glue these routes together and to make a table where the origin and destination of each route is listed and routes of the same car with at most 5 minutes in between are considered as one route.

I thank you in advance. Although I had some close attempts, a proper solution seems beyond my current (very basic) SQL-skills.